# ServiceNow instance scalability

Tags: servicenow

I am trying to understand the scalability or limit in terms of number of users , applications build or  integrations that can be set up on a single instance of ServiceNow production environment before we see performance degradation

Comment: servicenow will scale there systems accordingly

Comment: Maybe I should rephrase my question; what is the criteria for the need of a second instance of servicenow within an organization? What is the driver - is it governance or technical or both? if technical please do share some details

Comment: I don't see any reason to have multiple instances. One reason could be, if your company does HR work through Servicenow. But theirfore servicenow offers domain separation.

Comment: Most companies do have multiple instances, actually. Most common use case is something like 3 instances: DEV, TEST, PROD. It's very beneficial to have a non-production instance on which to develop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Our enterprise has about 20k employees (users), and we only have one instance of ServiceNow. We recently also launched HR within the same ITSM instance.

ServiceNow will scale accordingly without intervention (besides a Change notification/approval) from you/your company. Technically, i see no need for separate instances due to any limits of users, applications, or integrations.

Answer (score 1):

ServiceNow uses a dedicated set of Linux virtual machines for each instance. They behave as one, from the user's perspective, but can in fact have several "nodes". Performance can be scaled by changing the RAM/CPU of each node or by increasing the number of nodes. While this is interesting to know, customers of ServiceNow never need to worry about it. ServiceNow will scale an instance to meet the demand.  They offer a true Platform as a Service (PaaS). They usually use MySQL in the backend (also transparent to the user) but can choose to use Oracle ifthey need to scale the database beyond the limits of MySQL. Again, this is handled by ServiceNow themselves, so you don't have to worry 10 users or 10,000 users; You can just worry about getting your functionality right.

Answer (score 0):

Performance problems normally come from best practices not being followed. There is a list of them in the ServiceNow wiki.
You can always monitor the performance behaviour by looking at the sys transaction table. 
http://wiki.servicenow.com/index.php?title=System_Performance_Best_Practices#gsc.tab=0

The list of coding best practices are here: 
http://wiki.servicenow.com/index.php?title=Technical_Best_Practices#gsc.tab=0

Hope this helps,
Albert F
@qualityclouds